# "Run-time automation error -2147417848 (80010108)"

Tags: vba, excel

I use VBA excel to parse a long list of local `.htm` files. The problem is that I get an error even **before** the programm starts to parse the HTM-files.

**Error is:**

[image]

**VBA code:**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum
Sub ImportHTM()

    'Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    'Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate "d:\Cloud\Dropbox\3.htm"

    Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.StatusBar = "Loading Profile..." 'PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE SOMEWHERE!
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set html = ie.document
    Set ie = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""

'code code code --> which at this point isn't executed because the error occures before
```

Do you have any ideas what could cause the problem? Do you have any solution suggestions?

Also the command:

> ie.Visible = False

doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever since it opens the HTM-file in a new IE window.

Answer (score 0):

Move the status bar update out of the loop.

```
Application.StatusBar = "Loading Profile..."
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
```

There is no need to rewrite the same message into the [Application.StatusBar property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835916.aspx) hundreds if not thousands of times while you are waiting on a page load.

Regarding a new Internet.Explorer 'window' not inheriting the `.Visible = False` attribute, I recommend you switch to .Navigate2 and ShellWindows.

Addendum: Don't destroy your `ie` object until you are finished with the `html` associated with `ie.document`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've changed the code but still the same error... I think it has something to do with IE. Even if I try to load the local HTM file it takes some time... do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: tbh, currently I avoid going down the [Internet.Explorer object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx) rabbithole preferring the [IXMLHTTPRequest object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(v=vs.85).aspx) instead. So in all honesty I could only recommend using XMLHTTP or opening the file directly.